# Laravel 5.0.33 Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model not found in line 5

Tags: database, model, eloquent, laravel-5, illuminate-container

Here is my file `Email.php` in app, it is very simple but it doesn't work:

```
<?php
    namespace App;
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

    class Email extends Model {
        protected $table = 'emails';
        public $timestamps = false;
    }
?>
```

> Laravel 5.0.33 Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model not found in line 5

Comment: What is your problem? It does not work is not valid answer :)

Comment: The problem is that the class Model isn't found

Comment: Is your Laravel app installed?  Do you have `vendor` folder ?

Comment: try running 'composer install' from project root directory.